# How to calculate a Process Duration from a TimeSeries Dataset with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a huge dataset of various sensor data sorted chronologically (by timestamp) and by sensor type. I want to calculate the duration of a process in seconds by subtracting the first entry of a sensor from the last entry. This is to be done with python and pandas. Attached is an example for better understanding:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztO6v.jpg)

I want to subtract the first row from the last row for each sensor type to get the process duration in seconds (i.e. row 8 minus row 1 : 2022-04-04T09:44:56.962Z - 2022-04-04T09:44:56.507Z = 0.455 seconds).
The duration should then be written to a newly created column in the last row of the sensor type.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: welcome to SO! Please have a look here [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). please provide some of your data or a minimal-reproducable-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your 'timestamp' column is already 'to_datetime' converted, would this work ?

```
df['diffPerSensor_type']=df.groupby('sensor_type')['timestamp'].transform('last')-df.groupby('sensor_type')['timestamp'].transform('first')
```

You could then extract your seconds with this

```
df['diffPerSensor_type'].dt.seconds
```

Comment: I also only can think of transform because he wants a new column and not a scalar as output. But the extraction of the seconds won't work like you offered. I tried it aswell and since every result is less than 1 second the output would be 0 all the way.Replace `.dt.seconds` with `.div(np.timedelta64(1,"s")` and you get the actual results

Comment: Nice, I ll try that next time for more precision , thks! I wish I could try it again - but I already got rid of my made up input data..

Comment: just found out. you can also acces all attributes of the time with `dt.components` all the way down to nanoseconds. So `.dt.components.milliseconds` would also work

Answer (score 1):

If someone wants to reproduce an example, here is a df:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'sensor_type' : [0]*7 + [1]*11 + [13]*5 + [8]*5,
    'timestamp' : pd.date_range('2022-04-04', periods=28, freq='ms'),
    'value' : [128] * 28
})
df['time_diff in milliseconds'] = (df.groupby('sensor_type')['timestamp']
                   .transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]-x.iloc[0])
                   .dt.components.milliseconds)

print(df.head(10))
   sensor_type               timestamp  value  time_diff in milliseconds
0            0 2022-04-04 00:00:00.000    128                          6
1            0 2022-04-04 00:00:00.001    128                          6
2            0 2022-04-04 00:00:00.002    128                          6
3            0 2022-04-04 00:00:00.003    128                          6
4            0 2022-04-04 00:00:00.004    128                          6
5            0 2022-04-04 00:00:00.005    128                          6
6            0 2022-04-04 00:00:00.006    128                          6
7            1 2022-04-04 00:00:00.007    128                         10
8            1 2022-04-04 00:00:00.008    128                         10
9            1 2022-04-04 00:00:00.009    128                         10
```

My solution is nearly the same as @Daniel Weigel , only that I used `lambda` to calc the difference.